# p:selectCheckboxMenu and availables p:ajax events

Tags: events, primefaces

Ive been looking for all p:ajax events relateds with p:selectCheckBoxMenu

I need to click on selectCheckBoxMenu dropdown arrow and load again my object from bean.

Google it but with no success.

thanks in advance stack members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this on primefaces 5.2

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{mb.yourlistener}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the right answer from primefaces forum. Updating this post for further queries.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprSelect.jsf

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31975

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code for your specific primefaces version, for example for version 3.5 , see http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.5/org/primefaces/component/selectcheckboxmenu/SelectCheckboxMenu.java#SelectCheckboxMenu.0EVENT_NAMES

Answer (score 0):

Even in Primefaces 7.0.3 it's still "change" as default event and it seems "toggleSelect" for "changed all with the toggle everything checkbox".